# QtConcurrent::mapped return type issues

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use `QtConcurrent::mapped` to process a `std::vector` of data in parallel. Everything seems to work fine when I use a free function as the `MapFunctor` argument to `QtConcurrent::mapped`. However, when I use a lambda or a member pointer, the future returned is a `QFuture<void>`, not a `QFuture` of the result type. Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <QtConcurrent>

int free_func(int x) { return x + 3; }

struct S {
  int x;

  int func(S y) { return x + y.x; }
};

void example() {
  std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};

  QFuture<int> f1 = QtConcurrent::mapped(v, free_func);
  QFuture<int> f2 = QtConcurrent::mapped(v, [](int x) { return x + 1; });

  std::vector<S> v2 = {S{1}, S{2}, S{3}};
  QFuture<int> f3 = QtConcurrent::mapped(v2, &S::func);
}
```

As far as I can tell from reading [the Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html), this should all be fine. However, I get compilation errors for `f2` and `f3` that read

```
.../test.cpp:15: error: conversion from ‘QFuture<void>’ to non-scalar type ‘QFuture<int>’ requested
.../test.cpp: In function ‘void example()’:
.../test.cpp:15:41: error: conversion from ‘QFuture<void>’ to non-scalar type ‘QFuture<int>’ requested
   15 |   QFuture<int> f2 = QtConcurrent::mapped(v, [](int x) { return x + 1; });
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and something similar for `f3`. Why should `f2` and `f3` `QFuture<void>` instead of `QFuture<int>`?

(I know I have to actually use the futures after creating them, my question is just about the types of the futures.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version with `S::func` doesn't work because `func` has wrong signature.

If you have a collection `C`, `mapped` function iterates over all elements in this collection calling passed member function for each instance of `C`.

```
vector<S> C{S(1),S(2),..};
```

by

```
mapped(C,&S::func)
```

will be performed:

```
   C[0].func();
   C[1].func();
   ...
```

where above calls are performed by *map-function* whose signature is:

```
   RetType mapFunction(const S&)
```

member function is invoked for *const* object, so should be marked as *const* too.

```
struct S {
  int x;
  int func() const { return x + 1; } // + const and no arguments
};

void example() {
  std::vector<S> v2 {S{1}, S{2}, S{3}};
  QFuture<int> f3 = QtConcurrent::mapped(v2, &S::func);
```

Is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The automatic type deduction does not work with lambdas, you have to pass a proper std::function
`std::function<int(int)> f =  [](int x) { return x + 1; }; QFuture<int> f2 = QtConcurrent::mapped(v, f);`

f3 can't work since S::func() is no static function and therefore can't be used here.